# Быстрый поиск строки в файле с набором строк С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск

Имеется оочень много строк заданной длины, которые находятся в файле.

До начала поиска в файле с ним можно творить что угодно (например, сортировать), так же можно использовать дополнительную память.

После всех манипуляций с файлом в нем нужно **как можно быстрее** найти (или не найти, в зависимости от наличия) строку

Какие есть варианты поиска? :)

Comment: Что значит "заданной длины"? Все строки в файле имеют строго *одинаковую* длину?

Comment: Построить хэш для каждой строки в файле и готово.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте готовые алгоритмы, например [Ахо — Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA)a.

Если кратко, то вот идея. Пусть есть строки abc, abd dce.  Видно, что первые две строки имеют одинаковое начало. Поэтому, есть смысл искать только либо a либо d. И только когда один с этих символов найдет, проверять  b или c соответственно. Если кол-во строк больше кол-ва букв, то выхода уже очевидна.

Вторая идея. Если строк много, то есть ещё один "трюк". Если строки длинее допустим 4 байт (символов), то считает для них просто сумму первых 4 байт (или вспоминаем математику и придумываем свой хеш). А дальше просто бежим по файлу и считаем сумму очередных 4 байт. так как сумма 4 байт не будет больше 1024, то проверить, что текущая 4 байтная последовательность есть в списке очень быстро. Саму сумму можно всегда считать по принципу добавить текущий байт, вычесть байт на 4 (или 5, смотря как считать) позиции назад. В принципе можно поиграться длинной или функцией (хорошо xor может подойти) и получить минимум ложных срабатываний. Конечно, когда совпало начало, нужно проверять всю строку.

Comment: Алгоритм Ахо-Корасик предназначен для одновременного поиска нескольких строк и требует препроцессинга *искомых* строк. В условии задачи же ни слова нет о том, что искомые строки будут прибывать группами. И о препроцессинге речь идет только для *просматриваемых* строк. Поэтому с какого боку тут Ахо-Корасик - я что-то в упор не вижу.

Comment: Можно развернуть условие.

Answer (score 1):

*Извините, недостаточно репутации для комментария, поэтому отвечу. Если можно делать "что угодно" до поиска, то что мешает сделать список хешей строк файла? Тогда поиск будет заключаться в вычислении хеша искомой строки и его сравнения со списком.*

Можно отсортировать строки. Тогда поиск будет по такому алгоритму:

1. N=1, M=1
2. Сравниваем символ N искомой строки с символом N строки M. Если равны N=N+1 повторяем шаг 2, иначе шаг 3.
3. M=M+1 (переход к следующей строке), сравниваем символы 1..N искомой строки и строки M. Если равны повторяем шаг 2, иначе искомой строки нет (прерываем поиск).

Добавлю: Чтоб не сравнивать начальные символы в каждой строке, можно после сортировки к каждой строке привязать число равное длине одинакового числа символов от начала строки. Тогда на шаге 3 проверяем, что N-1 <= K (длина одинакового участка с предыдущей строкой). Если N-1 > K, то искомой строки нет.

Пример:

0-абвгд (нет одинакового участка с предыдущей)

3-абвее (три первых
   символа совпадают)

0-бббав (нет совпадений)

0-дееее (нет совпадений)

4-дееет (4 первых символа совпадают)

Поиск: "абвги"
На втором шаге дойдем до 5 символа. на третьем шаге N-1 > 3, значит искомой строки нет.

Comment: а как это поможет? манипуляции, то будут проводить над строками, а не над хешами?

Comment: Не внимательно прочитал вопрос. Строки одинаковой длины же даны. Я же правильно понимаю, все строки файла и искомая строка одинаковой длины? Т.е. ищем не подстроку, а именно строку целиком?

Comment: @dr-f-i-n да, правильно. Ищем строку.

Comment: @dr-f-i-n нууу, как-то так и сделал :)

Answer (score 1):

Хешировать в хеш-таблицу, в которой кроме хеша хранить позицию начала строки в файле. Может, еще и какой-то другой дайджест вроде sha256 :)

Тогда вы просто вычисляете хеш. При коллизиях используете этот дайджест, и получаете позицию в файле в конечном итоге.